# How to Group By some id and Sum all row json encode data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

```
I have Faced group by some id and Sum other column json_encode data in select query MySQL.
But how to sum total json data value?
Please help Anyone...
```

Using this,
    PHP 7.2, Mysql 5 and Apache 2.

```
I am try code
    > SELECT `fk_club_id`,`adpoints`,`actpoints`,(JSON_OBJECT('actpoints',
    > actpoints, 'adpoints', adpoints)) FROM (SELECT `fk_club_id`,
    > SUM(JSON_EXTRACT("$.adpoints")) as adpoints,
    > SUM(JSON_EXTRACT("$.actpoints")) as actpoints FROM club_scoresheet
    > where status= 1 GROUP BY `fk_club_id`) as t
```

MY table data ,

> ```
>     id  |  JSON  column()
>
>     15    ['5','6','2']
>     15    ['5','6','2']
>     28    ['5','6','1']
>     28    ['5','6','1']
>     28    ['5','6','1']
> ```

it is my table

My expectation result,

> ```
> id  | JSON column( total)
>
> 15     26
> 28     36
> ```

expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL version 5.7, JSON functions were introduced that could solve your problem. You could use the following, but it only allows to retrieve the sums when a fixed number of items is included in your JSON. Your example points out that there are 3 items in every JSON array, so you should be fine:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON,'$[0]') AS UNSIGNED)+CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON,'$[1]') AS UNSIGNED)+CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(JSON,'$[2]') AS UNSIGNED)) AS TOTAL FROM TEST GROUP BY ID;
```

If you would upgrade to MySQL 8, you could also use the new JSON_TABLE function to process any number of items in the JSON array:

```
SELECT TEST.ID,SUM(t.VAL) AS TOTAL FROM TEST, JSON_TABLE(JSON, '$[*]' COLUMNS(VAL INT PATH '$')) t GROUP BY ID
```

You can test this out in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/54XVfnZH6AKvTXnbSeX71n/0) as well.